# Exclude folders from TFS source control check-in policy

Tags: c#, tfs, policy, checkin

I have a tfs team project which includes both existing old classic asp web applications and new .net c# applications

I would like to enforce code analysis check-in policy in the .net apps, but when I do that, TFS requires us to "build" the classic asp website in order to analyze code before checking-in files even if there is no managed code to analyze in these apps, and otherwise no need to build anything.

So is there a way to exclude these source control folders from the check-in policy ?

I know with Custom Path Policy I can include folders in the check-in policy, but I would like not being required to add every new .net app folder each time, because we won't create new classic asp apps, but we will obviously create new .net apps.

thanks